# Convert Source Code into English Text?

Tags: parsers

Is there a way to convert, i.e., C code into English? The purpose would be to convert source code into a Text-To-Speech converter which would enable someone to "listen" to source code.

**EDIT:** An alternative idea would be to parse C code to be more "listenable", for example parse:

```
#include<stdio.h>

    funcName()
    {
        printf("Hello World");

    }
```

as

```
    hash include left-angle-bracket stdio.h right-angle-bracket
    newline
    camelcase funcName open-paren close-paren
    newline
    open bracket
    newline
    printf open-paren quote-mark Hello World quote-mark close-paren semi-colon
    newline
    close-bracket
```

Comment: Yes, the second idea seems like standard substitution. Just replace the occurences. With camelCase it would also require to check the tokens. The first one - it depends what you mean by converting into English. Please keep in mind that you do not need to put "Edit" into the text, there is revisions history available. I think you can do better than tokenizing, it would be possible to say "string" and ignore quotemarks, say that some standard library is included without reading #< .h>, but for now it is not fully clear what do you expect. Also listening to "newline" seems redundant...

Comment: This is more of a programming exercise. The parsing problem for C has been solved literally decades ago.

Comment: The title sounded like you wanted a program that'd describe C code in native English, but your actual question's a lot simpler.  You could really just use a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) command to do those replacements in a common text editor, e.g. in [Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Actually, as-asked, this seems more like a StackOverflow or even a SuperUser question than a CS question.

Comment: @nat I would use `sed` it is a streaming text editor. e.g. `sed -r -e 's/\{/open bracket/g' -e …`